# Skip/pass over view function so the next can execute in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app which currently has something like the following:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "homepage"

@app.route('/<slug>')
def feature(slug):
    return "feature: " + slug

@app.route('/<path:url>')
def catch(url):
    return "catch: " + url
```

This works in in that the following is true:

- `GET /` => "homepage"
- `GET /test1` => "feature: test1"
- `GET /test/2` => "catch: test/2"

Eventually, all this will be database driven. For features, they will be retrieved and displayed based on the slug. For the `catch`, they'll be loaded from the database and may result in some behaviour such as a redirect, or return a 404. None of this is a problem.

My question is this: in the `/test1` example, I'd like to achieve the following behaviour:

1. Attempt to load from the database where slug matches `test1`
2. If it exists, fine. Display.
3. If it does not exist, I'd like to "fall through" to the `catch` view function.

Point 3 is the part I don't know how to achieve. It seems like something that ought to exist, but I can't find any kind of "fall through to the next matching view function" behaviour anywhere. Is this possible and if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want use conditional logic for routes - it's probably not best point for routes.

However:

1. You can call another route on condition, but in some cases `request` fields can be different for this call and direct route call:

   ```
   @app.route('/<slug>')
   def feature(slug):
       if slug_in_database(slug):
           return "feature: " + slug
       return catch(slug)

   @app.route('/<path:url>')
   def catch(url):
       return "catch: " + url
   ```
2. Solution with right `request` object:

   ```
   @app.route('/<slug>')
   def feature(slug):
       if slug_in_database(slug):
           return "feature: " + slug
       with app.test_request_context(url_for('catch', url=slug))
           return catch(slug)

   @app.route('/<path:url>')
   def catch(url):
       return "catch: " + url
   ```
3. But I like just condition:

   ```
   @app.route('/<path:url>')
   def feature_or_catch(url):
       slug  = url
       if '/' not in slug and slug_in_database(slug):
           return "feature: " + slug
       return "catch: " + url
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This pretty much confirms that I wasn't missing anything in my original approach - but had gotten so bogged down in the problem I missed the obvious. :-)